# Adding rows to a data frame using cor() is not working properly in R

Tags: r, sorting, frame, correlation

I am trying to create a neat list of correlation values, which I then want to sort. However, when I try to produce this list, I obtain a list with the correlation variables pasted around my text.

I am using a for loop that is based on two `if` conditions. When the condition is true, I want to add the correlation value to the data frame. If it is not true, the value has to be 0. I have tried to use `rbind()` to add all rows together after running through one of the two conditions.

**edit** I tried adding `cbind(corl, i)` in each of the `if` conditions, in order to specify the associated index value for each correlation output, or 0 when if-condition is not met. This throws the error "names do not match previous names". Furthermore, I tried to add `cbind()` at the end of the for-loop (see `##`), but this also returns an error.

However, I get an error warning when I want to `cbind()` correlation values alongside fixed `0` values (e.g. when the condition is false).

My code is currently as follows:

```
## correlation function

corr <- function(directory, threshold = 0) {
    
    idFiles <- data.frame();
    fileList <- dir(directory, full.names = TRUE);
    
    listLength <- 1:length(fileList);
        convert <- sprintf("%03d", listLength);
        
    for (i in listLength) {
        
        data <- read.csv(fileList[i]);
        idFiles <- rbind(idFiles, data);        
    
    }
    
    cases <- complete(direct, 1:length(fileList));
    corl <- data.frame();
    frame <- data.frame();
    
    for (i in listLength) {
        
        if (cases[i, 2] > threshold) {
            
            monitor <- subset(idFiles, ID == i);
            monitor <- na.omit(monitor);
            corl <- cor(monitor["nitrate"], monitor["sulfate"]);
            frame <- rbind(frame, corl);
        }
        
        else {  
            
            corl <- 0;
            frame <- rbind(frame, corl);
            }
    }
    ##frame <- cbind.fill(frame, listLength);
    
    frame <- as.matrix(frame);
    print(frame);
    
}
```

When I run the function now, the output is, as mentioned, a list of values, but alas without a clean index. The text of the correlation function (nitrate and sulfate), surrounds the index value and makes the table difficult to interpret. As well, I cannot run the `sort()` function on this table, to sort the values from e.g. high to low, based on the index number.

Could anyone provide me with a suggestion on how to obtain a tidy list with indexes for the correlation values, which can be sorted from e.g. increasing to decreasing values, while keeping the link to the index number?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What does the error say? What is cases?

Comment: I solved the first part of indexing, by adding rbind within the if-statements, and cbind after the for loop. Sort now works as well. However, there seems to be something wrong with the calculation, as the expected output is wrong.

Comment: And now a new problem arises: when I input a value for the threshold of cases (another function that gives a value for the number of data rows in a file without any missing values), I get the error: "names do not match previous names". The statement (cases[i, 2] > threshold) does work in the command line. Can anybody tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: Please edit your question with your findings and a completely reproducible example. It's hard to know what's going on without seeing what cases is, at least it's hard for me.

Comment: cases is a function (cases.r) that determines the total number of observations without NA values in a file. Based on the threshold for the complete number of cases, I want to calculate the correlation between two variables present in the files (i.e. sulfate and nitrate). The in cases [ i , 2], the i defines the ID of the file, and " ,2" defines the second column in the obtained matrix, which has the value of the complete number of cases. When the threshold is not met, the return value has to be zero.

Comment: However, there seems to be a problem when row-binding the correlation values / output, and simple "zeroes / 0". E.g. I get the error "names do not match previous names", and also the function does not work for every threshold input value (for example, setting threshold to 100 works, but when I set it to e.g. 135, I get an error). Thanks!